# C memcpy unsigned char to 1 element unsigned char array for checksum calculation

Tags: c, memcpy, unsigned-char

There is a char array `ACKbuffer[2]` so I first cast to `unsigned char` the element that I want but it's giving me an error when I try to `memcpy` it to an `unsigned char` array.

```
//first element is checksum
unsigned char ack_csum;
ack_csum = (unsigned char)ACKbuffer[0];
//second element is ACK which needs to be run through checksum 
//in a checksum function that accepts unsigned char array as parameter
unsigned char ACK_actual = (unsigned char)ACKbuffer[1];
unsigned char ACK [1];
memcpy(ACK, ACK_actual, 1);
```

Error:

```
note: expected ‘const void * restrict’ but argument is of type ‘unsigned char’
 extern void *memcpy (void *__restrict __dest, const void *__restrict __src,
              ^~~~~~
swap_client.c: In function ‘swap_write’:
swap_client.c:185:17: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘memcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     memcpy(ACK, ACK_actual, 1);
```

I also tried another way but I get `invalid initializer`:

```
unsigned char ACK_actual = (unsigned char)ACKbuffer[1];
unsigned char ACK [1] = ACK_actual;
```

Ideally, I want my `ACK` array to hold that value from `ACKbuffer`.

Comment: `memcpy(ACK, ACK_actual, 1);` -> `memcpy(ACK, &ACK_actual, 1);`. `ACK_actual` is not a pointer and neither an array that decays to a pointer. Or `unsigned char ACK [1] = {ACK_actual};`.

Comment: I resorted to using `memset(ACK, ACK_actual, sizeof(ACK_actual));` It compiled but is this wrong?

Comment: That works as well, but why make it so complicated? `unsigned char ACK [1] = {ACKbuffer[1]};` works fine since C99. Why do you need the one-element array in the first place?

Comment: @walnut the checksum function accepts unsigned char arrays as input of varying length.  I use the same function to calculate checksum of up to 125 byte long messages as well as 1 byte ACK.

Comment: IMHO this smells like using a C++ compiler to compile C.

Comment: @mLstudent33 How did you declare that function?

Comment: `gcc test_swap_server.c swap_server.c sdp.c -o tester_s` That is the command used to compile.  How can I tell if it's for C++ or C?

Comment: @walnut `unsigned char checksum(unsigned char message [], int num_bytes)`

Comment: @mLstudent33 `unsigned char message []` is a pointer. You can pass `&ACK_actual` directly to it. You are compiling as C, that is not an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this call of memcpy

```
memcpy(ACK, ACK_actual, 1);
```

the variable ACK_actual has the type unsigned char

```
unsigned char ACK_actual = (unsigned char)ACKbuffer[1];
```

but the function expects a pointer type.

Just write

```
memcpy(ACK, ACKbuffer + 1, 1);
```

As for the second code snippet then you should write

```
unsigned char ACK_actual = (unsigned char)ACKbuffer[1];
unsigned char ACK [1] = { ACK_actual };
```

Comment: But this would copy the entire `ACKbuffer` wouldn't it?  I just want the second element.

Comment: @mLstudent33 Why? There is explicitly specified to copy 1 byte.

Comment: @mLstudent33 The was a typo. Should be ACKbuffer + 1

Comment: That's awesome, I just updated the question to show more info.

Comment: btw, the conversion from `char` to `unsigned char` is automatic with `memcpy`?

Comment: @mLstudent33 The function arguments are pointers to void. And a pointer to an object of any type can be implicitly converted to pointer to void.

Comment: The suggestion of using ACKbuffer + 1 assumes ACKbuffer is of type char which is not specified in the question. The only sure answer is using &ACK_actual.

Comment: @cquezel There is clear written in the question that it is a character array.

Comment: @cquezel I added two more lines of code to clarify.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow you're right, Did not read the question, only the code.